# How To Efficiently Design Nested OPTIONAL Clauses In SPARQL

Tags: sparql, option-type

I want to retrieve data that has optional elements at multiple levels.  For example, assume I have four ancestors - Fred, Sam, George, and Mark.  Fred and Sam have kids ... George and Mark do not.   All of Fred's kids have nicknames, but two of Sam's four kids do not.

I want to query all of the kids of my ancestors and return their names, ages, and nicknames.

It seems like this would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?token ?ancestorName ?childName ?childAge ?childNickname
WHERE
{
    FILTER      ( ?token IN ("Fred","Sam","George","Mark") )
    ?ancestor     foo:name      ?token        .
    ?ancestor     foo:fullname  ?ancestorName .
    OPTIONAL
    {
        ?ancestor     foo:parentOf      ?child         .
    ?child        foo:fullname      ?childName     .
        ?child        foo:age           ?childAge      .
        OPTIONAL { ?child  foo:nickname ?childNickname  }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine if an ancestor doesn't have a child ... all of the outer optional clause returns quickly
with no data.  If the ancestor has children, and each has a nickname, it returns quickly and fills in the data.  The problem seems to happen when the ancestor has a child, but the child does not have a nickname.

It works ... but it takes a very long time (I have lots of data).  It appears that the inner `OPTIONAL` clause

```
OPTIONAL { ?child  foo:nickname ?childNickname  }
```

... does a cross product ... combining every `?child` with every `?childNickname` ... and then returns the right value.

How can I write this SPARQL `SELECT` to run efficiently (not do a cross product) and return all of the ancestors and all of the kids even if a kid doesn't have a nickname?  I've tried `FILTERS`.  I've tried checking whether `?child` was `BOUND`.   I haven't found the secret to make it run quick.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: An OPTIONAL is a left-outer-join. evaluation is done bottom-up. I don"t see any optimization potential here, this has to be done by the triple store

Comment: Possibly a thing to try is to use a `VALUES` clauses instead of the `FILTER ... IN` for the tokens. But like @AKSW said it depends on the triplestore you're using (and how clever its query planner is) whether that will have any effect.

Comment: Ah, right. Inline data might help indeed.